# json response comparison between two files

Tags: json

My boss told me to compare json response and automate it. For eg: Store the json response which are coming from server and store them in one file now make second file to call first file and compare each json response. If response is right then automatically it will check mark saying "all response are correct" and vice versa. But I don't know how to do it. Can anyone guide me ?

Comment: you might want to `Serialize` the `json` and then do comparing.

Comment: *De*serialize, you mean.

Comment: which language are you working on?

Comment: jquery, ajax , html and php.